# Cake PHP: HTML Helper inside Element does not work

Tags: php, html, cakephp, helper

I make a call like: $this->element('stories') in order to display the contents of this element named "stories" in multiple pages. When I use the html helper inside the element, I get the following error: Missing Helper Error: htmlHelper could not be found.

Note: I am using CakePHP 2.4

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you enabled Htmlhelper in all your controllers? Also: HtmlHelper with capital 'H'

Comment: Yeah, mind your casing - as with almost everything related to programming and operating systems (even if you are coming from Windows^^).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html helper like..

```
<?php 
   // not echo $html->link('text', 'url'); 
   // not echo $this->html->link('text', 'url'); 
   echo $this->Html->link('text', 'url'); 
?>
```

Please check your code. Please have a look on the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html).

Comment: also, don't forget the `echo`